# example use of custom user claims of firebase documentation doesn't work

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I've tried to follow this guide to create three roles that I need on client side to show different UIs

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

at first I initialize firebase on my public void run,  at the main .java

```
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("MyRoute\\serviceAccountKey.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
        .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

then I use custom user claims on my User controller the same way as in the guide
UserController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private User createStudent(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {
    //Create the new User
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserType(UserType.STUDENT);
    user.setEmail(userDTO.getEmail());
    user.setFirstName(userDTO.getFirstName());
    user.setLastName(userDTO.getLastName());
    //verify the user and create custom role
    String idToken = userDTO.getIdToken();
    Task<FirebaseToken> decoded = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(idToken);
    Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
    claims.put("student", true);
    String uid = decoded.getUid(); 
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().setCustomUserClaims(uid, claims);

    return userService.save(user);
```

With two errors
first of all I can't get uid with `decoded.getUid()` like documentation says 
because it forces me to use Task instead FirebaseToken

and secondly I can't use `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().setCustomUserClaims(uid, claims);`

because it says The method setCustomUserClaims(String, Map) is undefined for the type FirebaseAuth

if I change `setCustomUserClaims` to `setCustomClaims` as eclipse suggests me I get the following error
The method setCustomClaims(String, Map) from the type FirebaseAuth is not visible

Is my first time with firebase so I'm at loss why this doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an old version of the SDK. `Task` API was removed in the 6.0.0 release. Blocking methods like `setCustomUserClaims()` were added in the same release. If you want to keep using the old version then following should work:

```
ApiFuture<Void> result = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().setCustomUserClaimsAsync(uid, claims);
```

Comment: I don't know what happened I thought I had 6.2.0 version on maven but I had the 5.9 one.  thanks now with version 6.0 it works!